# Including JSON files as part of Python package

Tags: python, pip, package

I`m writing a package with a "local database" consisting of a folder and subfolders with json files. My database.py module imports these files with a relative path to them (DB_PATH). When installing the package, load fails since files are not found. Is there a way to import those files as part of the package, or a standard way to handle cases like this?

My python code database.py:

```
DB_PATH = "./db"


def getIndex():
    filename = f"{DB_PATH}/index.json"

    with open(filename) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    return data
```

File system:

```
package
 ┣folder
 ┃ ┗project
 ┃   ┣db
 ┃   ┃ ┣ index.json
 ┃   ┃ ┗config
 ┃   ┃   ┣ conf_1.json
 ┃   ┃   ┣ conf_2.json
 ┃   ┃   ┗ ...
 ┃   ┗ database.py
 ┗setup.py
```

Comment: How do you install the package? pip install? python setup.py install? Are files exist in the destination install folder?

Comment: @Corralien I have a setup.py file and install with pip install <github_path>. The setup.py is two levels above project/

Comment: usually, using "./folder" is relative to where the running script is. in your folder structure there is no "db" folder in the same level as the database.py level. also, why "db" and not "database"?

Comment: Folder is called db my mistake. Will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `setup.py`, add this line:

```
import glob

setup(
    ...
    data_files=glob.glob('project/db/**')
)
```

In your `database.py`

```
import os.path

DB_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'db')
```

The variable `__file__` contains the absolute path of the current python script `database.py`. Use `dirname` to get the parent folder and `join` to add `database` directory in the path.

Comment: For the benefit of all, would you explain why using `os.path.dirname(__file__)` is correct?

Comment: @Oren_C. I added some explanation. Is it clear now?